# initialise svnsync command from slave svn server

Tags: apache, svn, hook, svnsync

I have a setup of master-slave SVN servers.

Master and two Slave server are set up in three different location of three different timezone. We cannot let the slave server up for 24 hrs, so slave servers need to be shut down at the end of each day. But at the same time developers are committing changes from another slave to master server. Master server is up forever.

So my situation is at the starting of the day each slave server needs to synchronized with master which can only done from master by svnsync command. 

**Is there any way to automatically synchronize slave server when it starts up?**

We are using apache server to host subversion. OS are windows server 2008 R2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using `svnsync` on your slave server in a boot time script is not possible, you can do something like the solution described in [this blog post](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2008/11/subversion_replication_at_atla/).

To sum it up, then have a dedicated server listening on the master server (written in Python) that will start `svnsync` upon reception of a special TCP packet.

On your slave, you can then use the [Windows version](http://joncraton.org/blog/46/netcat-for-windows) of [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) like described in the blog post to trigger the sync.